# Compiler warning about printf() long unsigned int and uint32_t

Tags: c, linux, gcc, printf

In my C code, I'm `fprintf`ing a `"%lu"` and giving a `uint32_t` for the corresponding field.  But, when I compile with `-Wall` in GCC (ver. 4.2.4), I get the following warning:

```
writeresults.c:16: warning: format '%4lu' expects type 'long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 
`uint32_t'
```

Aren't a `uint32_t` and `long unsigned int` the same thing on 32-bit architectures?  Can this warning be avoided without eliminating the `-Wall` compiler switch or using a typecast (and if so, how)?

Yes, I'm still using a 32-bit computer/arch/OS/compiler (too poor at the moment to afford new 64-bit HW).  Thanks!

Comment: Real question: "How do I get gcc to *not* warn on {%d with long}, on machines where long == int, because for some reason (likely MS compat) the int32_t has been defined as long instead of int on the machine, and people insist on using int32_t everywhere, and I really don't want to put (int) in front of every single thing passed to printf".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uint32_t` on x86 Linux with GCC is just `unsigned int`. So use `fprintf(stream, "%4u", ...)` (unsigned int) or better yet, `fprintf(stream, "%4" PRIu32, ...)` (the `inttypes.h` printf-string specifier for `uint32_t`).

The latter will definitely eliminate the compiler warning / error, and, additionally, is cross-platform.

Comment: Uh, where is the "bad" casting you're referring to? `PRIu32` *is* the define that handles `uint32_t` correctly.

Comment: Oh my, you are right!  I'm wrong. Thanks.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to reliably suppress the warning is with a cast:

```
printf( "%lu", ( unsigned long )x );
```

Comment: ...and this is perfectly portable, since the minimal allowed size of `unsigned long` is exactly sufficient to hold all values of type `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

"long int" and "int" are different types in C++. You might be looking for the "u" format, which stands for "unsigned int". Of course, this depends on what "uint32_t" is a typedef for on your compiler.

Comment: In cases where they are the same size, the compiler is aware of this, and it can thus know ("%d",  (long)x ) will work fine, but it's warning you because that construct won't work on other machines. Unless, of course, the 'long' is really an int32_t typedef, in which case it will work on any machine with int =32 bits. I'd prefer if there a way to back this off, and only warn about things that *really* are wrong in the current situation.